# iptables inside bridge

Tags: iptables, bridge, forwarding

if i have:

```
eth0  (no address)
wlan0 (no address, providing wifi-hotspot by 'hostapd')
br0   (local IP, bridging eth0+wlan0)
eth1  (public IP, providing internet to above by net.ipv4.ip_forward=1)
```

and i want to:

block targetPublicIP only to eth0 (so that wlan0 clients CAN, and eth0 clients CAN NOT acess it).

This is not working:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d targetPublicIP -j DROP
```

probably because iptables can not interfere inside bridge which is level2 or something... i have never used ebtables, maybe that can be solution, or ip rules, or what?

What is the simplest solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

seems that "physdev" was the option i was looking for:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 -d targedPublicIp -j DROP
```

working ok, no need for learning ebtables for now.